# Online algorithm to compute variance with a decay

Tags: variance, online-algorithms

Could somebody point me to an online algorithm that computes the variance, but gives a higher weight to more recent values?

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610910600880328).

Comment: [This algorithm](http://www.squobble.com/academic/doc/vanvaerenbergh2012_krls_tracker_tnnls.pdf) has a forgetting factor so that it gradually forgets older data. It does time series prediction and it estimates the variance as well.