# Online estimation of variance with limited memory

Tags: variance, online-algorithms

I am creating a component that aims to calculate the average and variance of a metric associated with events happening during time but with a limited internal memory.

Imagine that the events are visitors entering in a shop and the metric is their age.

During time, my component receives events with the age of each visitor.
I don't want my component to memorize the history of each ages.
Ideally, I would like a light component storing only:
the average `A`, the variance V and the number of events `N`.

After each event with age `E`, I want to update those three values :

```
N<=N+1
A<=(A*N+E)/(N+1)
V<=???
```

What for `V`? I am thinking of something like :

```
V<=(V*N+(E-A)^2)/(N+1)
```

I know it is not exact as my previous `V` is using the old `A` which is no more the average.

Q1 - Is there an exact formula?
Q2 - If not, is my proposal a good estimate? Is it biased? Will it converge correctly when `N` increases?
Q3 - Is there a better formula?

Comment: Numerical accuracy might be a concern too. And see also [Online algorithm to compute variance with a decay](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44252/17230).

Comment: Can you also keep the sum of E^2?

Comment: Yes It would be OK. I can keep a finite number of values but not depending on N.

Comment: Use a numerically stable one-pass variance updating algorithm as provided, for instance, in section 1 of http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr222.pdf . The answer by Andy W. is a terrible method which can be very inaccurate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nice and simple [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) for computing variance in online manner was described by Welford (1962). Below you can see C++/Rcpp implementation of it that works offline, but can be easily adapted to online scenario:

```c
List welford_cpp(NumericVector x) {
  
  int n = x.length();
  double delta;
  double msq = 0;
  double mean = x[0];
  
  if (n > 1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { 
      delta = x[i] - mean;
      mean += delta / (i+1);
      msq += delta * (x[i] - mean);
    }
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("mean") = mean,
                              Rcpp::Named("variance") = msq / (n-1));
  }
  
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("mean") = mean,
                            Rcpp::Named("variance") = NAN);
}
```

As you can see, it needs to store only four variables: `n`, `delta`, `msq` and `mean` and computes mean and variance simultaneously as you wanted.

---

Welford, B. P. (1962). [Note on a method for calculating corrected sums of squares and products](https://doi.org/10.1080/00401706.1962.10490022). Technometrics 4(3): 419-420.

Comment: Why on earth doesn't the msq increase by delta**2? And you don't really need to store delta? It's convenience. You don't use delta from the previous loop for anything. Edit: Ah, I see. We've changed mean.

Comment: @grofte see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_online_algorithm and you're correct, there's no need to store delta.

Answer (score 1):

The variance can be expressed as proportional to the squared difference between every value and the mean value, or (as many threads here in stats.SE documented, like [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/225753/60613) I wrote to another question) it can alternatively be expressed as proportional to the squared pairwise difference between every sample.

So we know:

$$\text {Var}(x) = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i}(X_i-\overline{X})^2 = 
\frac{1}{2n^2} \cdot \sum_{i,j}(X_i-X_j)^2$$

Let's say you add another sample, indexed as the last index, $k$. Your previous variance would be:

$$\text {Var}_{old}(x) = \frac{1}{2(n-1)^2} \cdot \sum_{i<k,j<k}(X_i-X_j)^2$$

Your new variance is

$$\text {Var}_{new}(x) = \frac{1}{2n^2} \cdot \sum_{i,j}(X_i-X_j)^2 =
\frac{1}{2n^2} \cdot 
\left(
\sum_{i<k,j<k}(X_i-X_j)^2 + \sum_{j<k}(X_k-X_j)^2 + \sum_{i<k}(X_i-X_k)^2
\right)$$

But

$$\sum_{j<k}(X_k-X_j)^2 = \sum_{i<k}(X_i-X_k)^2\\
\sum_{i<k,j<k}(X_i-X_j)^2 = {2(n-1)^2} \cdot \text {Var}_{old}(x)
$$

So

$$\text {Var}_{new}(x) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2
\text{Var}_{old}(x)+
\frac{1}{n^2}
\sum_{j<k}(X_k-X_j)^2
$$

As @MarkL.Stone said in the comments, this still isn't efficient because we must keep every $X_i$. So, let's expand the formula to arrive at something more tractable.

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j<k}(X_k-X_j)^2=\\
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j<k}(X_k^2 - 2 \cdot X_j \cdot X_k + X_j^2)=\\
\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{j<k}X_k^2 - 2 \cdot X_k \cdot \sum_{j<k} X_j + \sum_{j<k} X_j^2\right)=\\
\frac{1}{n^2}\left(k\cdot X_k^2 - 2 \cdot X_k \cdot (k-1) \cdot \overline{X_{old}} + (k-1) \cdot \overline{X^2_{old}}\right)\\
$$
Because
$$\sum_{j<k} X_j = (k-1) \cdot \overline{X_{old}}\\
\sum_{j<k} X_j^2 = (k-1) \cdot \overline{X^2_{old}}$$

The final form is then

$$\text {Var}_{new}(x) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2
\text{Var}_{old}(x)+
\frac{1}{n^2}\left(k\cdot X_k^2 - 2 \cdot X_k \cdot (k-1) \cdot \overline{X_{old}} + (k-1) \cdot \overline{X^2_{old}}\right)
$$

You can use this formula to update the variance effectively memory-wise. You can also complement it to use batches instead of single point updates.

Basically you need to store the average, the average of the squared samples, and the variance every iteration, and use it to update the variance formula.

---

Further

$$\overline{X^2_{old}} = \text{Var}_{old}(x) + (\overline{X_{old}})^2\\
\therefore\text {Var}_{new}(x) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2
\text{Var}_{old}(x)+
\frac{1}{n^2}\left(k\cdot X_k^2 - 2 \cdot X_k \cdot (k-1) \cdot \overline{X_{old}} + (k-1) \cdot \left(\text{Var}_{old}(x) + (\overline{X_{old}})^2\right)\right)
$$

Which brings the number of quantities that need to be stored down to 2.

Comment: Doesn't this method require the availability of all previous data points in order to compute the update? If so, that is in contravention to the idea of dealing with limited memory. Note that online updating algorithms, along the lines of Welford's in the answer by @Tim , which is a particular instance of a class of similar algorithms discussed in cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr222.pdf , do not require saving old data points, but only 2 registers (scalar variables) to retain old information.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Hmm I see. Yes, this requires all the previous values $X_i$, you are right.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I updated the formula so three scalars need to be stored. I can already see it can be further reduced, perhaps being equivalent to the other solution.

Comment: Due to the subtraction, rather than only adding non-negative quantities, your revised algorithm is less numerically accurate (robust) than the Welford and similar algorithms. I see no merit in it whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

OK Andy W gave the answer. By conserving the $E^2$ average in the same way as the E average, you can use $V = exp(E^2)-exp(E)^2$.

Comment: By $exp(E^2)$ do you perhaps mean the *expected value* of $E^2$? (And not the exponential function.)

Comment: That method is fine, unless you care about getting the right answer.

Comment: Yes exp(ectation). And why won't the answer be correct ? Is it a mathematic problem or a computational one ?

Comment: Numerical instability, and therefore, numerical inaccuracy. It is correct if performed in exact arithmetic, i.e., infinite precision.  In finite precision on a computer, it can be very inaccurate, and can even come out negative (and actually has on many occasions)..

Comment: Well, I trust you. But, I am inclined to make the following simple reasoning :  the relative error on an average is identical or less than the error on the value. So, the difference between 2 averages should not be really inaccurate unless close to 0.

Comment: Excel actually used this method for a long time (to much criticism and derision from statisticians and others). In quite simple circumstances (data with large mean, small standard deviation) you could make its variance function give output that corresponded to an approximation of a random number generator (shift the data by successive small amounts and the reported variance jumped around dramatically). This was caused by catastrophic cancellation of the difference. It was a very effective way to demonstrate why these issues matter. Excel doesn't do that any more.

Comment: On this catastrophic cancellation, see for example the discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Formulae_for_the_variance)